# Why don't I see an increase in volume of the gas when the tube is rised up?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics

[image]

Since the point $p1$ is at the same level as the beaker surface, the pressure at $p_1$ is $1$ atm. Say $h=5cm$. What happens if I pull the tube up by $1cm$ ? Would the volume of ammonia gas increase ? (I've just tested this in my kitchen and found no noticeable difference in the volume of the gas).

My attempt :
Pressure at $p1$ is given by $$\color{red}{p_1}=\color{red}{p_2} + \rho * g* \color{red}{h} = p_2 + 10^3*10*5*10^{-2} = p_2+500 $$

Since $\color{red}{p_1}$ is fixed at $1$ atm, increasing $\color{red}{h}$ should decrease $p_2$, resulting in an increase in volume of the gas. But in my kitchen experiment I didn't notice any change in the volume. See anything wrong in my reasoning ? Thanks!

Comment: Hey $h$ is the height of the fluid above the point $p_1$.  Distance between the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ increases if I rise the tube up, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably not be able to observe the change in volume unless you have very precise measuring graduated cylinders.

When you lift the cylinder, you are lifting more water out of the basin which will add to the volume of water that wants to fall to a lower elevation. This will pull on the gas at the top and decrease the pressure which will increase the volume, but unless you have a large enough volume to observe the expansion you may not be able to measure it.

Comment: Thank you (: I'm thinking the same. But does $PV = constant$ apply here ? If so, if I decrease $p_2$ by half, shouldn't the volume of the gas double ?

Comment: Yes, but you are not decreasing the pressure by half unless you lift enough water to pull on the gas that much. If you were lifting mercury you would have to lift about 15 inches to decrease the pressure by half. Because the gas would expand you would have to lift a cylinder much longer than just 15 inches; probably several feet. If you have a 24 inch cylinder and sink it in a barrel leaving one inch of air you should be able to observe the volume of air increase but only just a little fraction of an inch.

Comment: water weights about 8lb / gallon, air at sea lvl is about 14.7 psi. To decrease pressure by half you need to lift nearly a gallon of water.

Comment: Awesome, I get it ! $p2$ becomes $0$ when $h$ equals $10m$. A height of $5cm$ is too small compared to $10m$... Thanks again :)